# Analytics + Full text search - Big data

Tags: hadoop, solr, full-text-search, hdfs, bigdata

I need to implement a system which derives **analytics/insights** from data (Text-only) as well as can do **complex search queries**.

So I have shortlisted **Solr(search)** and **Hadoop(Analytics)**. I am unable to decide which base should I use to start. **Can we integrate HDFS cluster with Solr?** I will be mainly dealing with aggregation queries and data will not update frequently.

I know this question is too broad and general. I just need a expert's opinion on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Cloudera Search](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Search/latest/Cloudera-Search-User-Guide/csug_introducing.html) and [this](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cdh/search.html)

Cloudera Search = SOLR + Hadoop

Using Cloudera Search, you can query the data in Hadoop or HBase using SOLR.